# jxmaps giving error while showing map

Tags: jxmaps

I am getting error while showing Google maps on my Java swing application with Jxmaps.

It shows me 
"Oops! Something went wrong. This page didn't load Google Maps correctly. See the JavaScript console for technical details."

message on my map component.

Is there anyone to help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error can be caused by missing or incorrect API KEY. Google Maps allows limited number of requests per day without API KEY.

Have you set it in JxMaps? You can do it with followed code:

```
MapViewOptions options = new MapViewOptions();
options.setApiKey("<YOUR_API_KEY>");
MapView view = new MapView(options);
```

More detailed information about Google Maps API keys you can find here: https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/